# Pandas Series.apply - use arguments from another Series?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following statement:

```
>>> df['result'] = df['value'].apply(myfunc, args=(x,y,z))
```

The Python function myfunc was written before I started using Pandas and is set up to take single values.  The arguments x and z are fixed and can easily be passed as a variable or literal, but I have a column in my DataFrame that represents the y parameter, so I'm looking for a way to use that row's value for each row (they differ from row to row).

i.e. df['y'] is a series of values that I'd like to send in to myfunc

My workaround is as follows:

```
values = list(df['value'])
y = list(df['y'])
df['result'] = pd.Series([myfunc(values[i],x,y[i],z) for i in range(0,len(values))])
```

Any better approaches?

**EDIT**

Using functools.partial has a gotcha that was able to work out.  If your call does not stick to keyword arguments then it appears to resort to positional and then you may run into the **'myfunc() got multiple values for...'** error.

I modified the answer from coldspeed:

```
# Function myfunc takes named arguments arg1, arg2, arg3 and arg4
#   The values for arg2 and arg4 don't change so I'll set them when
#   defining the partial (assume x and z have values set)
myfunc_p = partial(myfunc, arg2=x, arg4=z)
df['result'] = [myfunc_p(arg1=w, arg3=y) for w, y in zip(df['value'], df['y'])]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're doing is fine. I'd maybe make a couple of improvements:

```
from functools import partial
myfunc_p = partial(myfunc, x=x, z=z)
df['result'] = [myfunc_p(v, y) for v, y in zip(df['value'], df['y'])]
```

You don't need to wrap the list in a `pd.Series` call, and you can clean up your function call by fixing two of the arguments with `functools.partial`.

There's also the other option using `np.vectorize` (disclaimer, this does not actually vectorize the function, just hides the loop) for more concise code, but in most cases the list comprehension should be faster.

```
myfunc_v = np.vectorize(partial(myfunc, x=x, z=z))
df['result'] = myfunc_v(df['value'], df['y'])
```

Comment: Nice, thanks.  I came across partial but haven't used it before.

Answer (score 3):

You could also `apply` over the rows with a `lambda` like so:

```
df['result'] = df.apply(lambda row: myfunc(row['value'], y=row['y'], x=x, z=z), axis=1)
```